# Adding functions with a different x-axis

Tags: matlab, plot, addition, matlab-figure

How to add two functions with a different x-axis?

I plotted two different sets of data where one of the sets of data has a shifted x-axis. I now want to add these functions. Below is the code I used:

```
clc;

fid = fopen('n.csv');
readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','HeaderLine',1,'Delimiter',',');
x1data = readData{1,1}(:,1);
y1data = readData{1,2}(:,1);
y2data = readData{1,3}(:,1);
hold on
plot(x1data,y1data);
plot(x1data+0.5,y2data);
hold off
```

At this point, I would like to add them together. How to do that?

Comment: What do you mean by *adding the functions*?

Comment: Do you mean plotting the two functions to the same figure? Your code does that, no? Are you looking for two different x-axes in the same figure? Don't do that, it's a great way of misleading the reader. Instead, use two subfigures (see `subplot`).

Answer (score 0):

If you want use in one plot function you can do this

```
clc;
fid = fopen('n.csv');
readData = textscan(fid,'%f %f %f','HeaderLine',1,'Delimiter',',');
x1data = readData{1,1}(:,1);
y1data = readData{1,2}(:,1);
y2data = readData{1,3}(:,1);
plot(x1data,y1data,x1data+0.5,y2data);
```